# How to close lightbox and background overlay?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am currently adding a lightbox to a clients web page and I've managed to do so, however when I close the lightbox, the overlay in the background doesn't go away and stay sin position. I have to refresh the page for it to go away.

How can I allow the overlay to also close out when I click X Close to close the popup?

Here is the area where I think the issue is...

```html
<button id="LearnMoreBtn">PLEASE READ OUR PARTY POLICIES</button>

<div id="overlay"></div>
<div id="popup">
<a href="javascript:void(0)" onclick="document.getElementById('popup').style.display='none';">X Close</a>
```

Here is the entire code for the button/lightbox/ect..

```html
    <style>
  button
  {
    border-radius: 19px;
    background-color: limegreen;
    color: white;
    font-family: "Comic-sans", cursive, Sans-serif;
    margin-left: 33%;
  }
  
  #popup a
  {
    text-align: right;
    text-decoration: none;
    color: black;
  }
  
  #overlay {
    display:none;    
    position:fixed;
    left:0px;        
    top:0px;         
    width:100%;      
    height:100%; 
    background:#000; 
    opacity:0.5;    
    z-index:99999;
  }

  h5
  {
    text-align: center;
  }
  
  #popup {
    display:none;
    position:absolute;           
    width:1000px;         
    height:850px;
    margin-left: 10%;
    background:#FFFFFF;  
    border:2px solid #000;  
    z-index:100000; 
    color: black;
  }
</style>

<button id="LearnMoreBtn">PLEASE READ OUR PARTY POLICIES</button>
<div id="overlay"></div>
<div id="popup">
  <a href="javascript:void(0)" onclick="document.getElementById('popup').style.display='none';">X Close</a>

   <b><h5>
     Please read through our party policies!
   </h5></b>
    <br>
    <b>Party Schedule:</b> 
    The birthday party program will last two hours and include:
    <br>
  <ul>
    <li>30-minute welcome activity and building orientation </li>
    <li>60-minute hands-on program and project </li>
    <li>30-minute period for birthday celebration </li>
    <br>
  </ul>
  <b>The Museum staff who facilitate the party are flexible and will work with you to adjust the schedule for latecomers and other needs. The Museum provides: </b>
  <br>
  <ul>
    <li>A Museum teacher to lead the party. </li>
    <li>Supplies for each child to create a hands-on project (excluding the Block Party and Brick City Party). </li>
    <li>Exclusive use of a classroom starting 30 minutes before the party start time and ending 15 minutes after the party end time. </li>
    <li>The Museum will provide a safety lighter to light the birthday candles. <li>Please do not bring matches. </li>
    <li>One 5' round table and chairs will be provided to seat every 6-7 children. 
    <li>One additional table will be provided for refreshments. </li>
    <li>Party favors for each child. If you would like to provide goody bags or any additional favors, you can bring those and stuff them with the Museum-provided items before the party begins.</li> 
    <li> Museum t-shirt for the birthday child.</li>
  </ul>
  <br>
</div>

<script>
  window.onload = function() {
  
    document.getElementById("LearnMoreBtn").onclick = function(){

      var overlay = document.getElementById("overlay");
      var popup = document.getElementById("popup");
     
      overlay.style.display = "block";
      popup.style.display = "block";
   };
};
  
</script>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're just missing the behavior to close the `overlay`. In the code you use to display the `overlay` and `popup`, you update the display for both, but not on the close button.

I just added the event listener with the original code and connected it to the `close-button`. See below:

```html
    <style>
  button
  {
    border-radius: 19px;
    background-color: limegreen;
    color: white;
    font-family: "Comic-sans", cursive, Sans-serif;
    margin-left: 33%;
  }
  
  #popup a
  {
    text-align: right;
    text-decoration: none;
    color: black;
  }
  
  #overlay {
   display:none;    
   position:fixed;
   left:0px;        
   top:0px;         
   width:100%;      
   height:100%; 
   background:#000; 
   opacity:0.5;    
   z-index:99999;
}

  h5
  {
    text-align: center;
  }
  
#popup {
   display:none;
   position:absolute;           
   width:1000px;         
   height:850px;
  margin-left: 10%;
   background:#FFFFFF;  
   border:2px solid #000;  
   z-index:100000; 
   color: black;
}
</style>

<button id="LearnMoreBtn">PLEASE READ OUR PARTY POLICIES</button>
<div id="overlay"></div>
<div id="popup">
<a id="close-button" href="javascript:void(0)">X Close</a>

 <b><h5>
   Please read through our party policies!
 </h5></b>
  <br>
  <b>Party Schedule:</b> 
The birthday party program will last two hours and include:
<br>
<ul>
<li>30-minute welcome activity and building orientation </li>
<li>60-minute hands-on program and project </li>
<li>30-minute period for birthday celebration </li>
 <br>
  </ul>
<b>The Museum staff who facilitate the party are flexible and will work with you to adjust the schedule for latecomers and other needs. The Museum provides: </b>
  <br>
  <ul>
<li>A Museum teacher to lead the party. </li>
<li>Supplies for each child to create a hands-on project (excluding the Block Party and Brick City Party). </li>
<li>Exclusive use of a classroom starting 30 minutes before the party start time and ending 15 minutes after the party end time. </li>
<li>The Museum will provide a safety lighter to light the birthday candles. <li>Please do not bring matches. </li>
<li>One 5' round table and chairs will be provided to seat every 6-7 children. 
<li>One additional table will be provided for refreshments. </li>
<li>Party favors for each child. If you would like to provide goody bags or any additional favors, you can bring those and stuff them with the Museum-provided items before the party begins.</li> 
 <li> Museum t-shirt for the birthday child.</li>
  </ul>
  <br>
</div>

<script>
  window.onload = function() {
  
   document.getElementById("LearnMoreBtn").onclick = function(){

      var overlay = document.getElementById("overlay");
      var popup = document.getElementById("popup");
     
      overlay.style.display = "block";
      popup.style.display = "block";
   };

   document.getElementById("close-button").onclick = function() {
     var overlay = document.getElementById("overlay");
     var popup = document.getElementById("popup");
     
     overlay.style.display = "none";
     popup.style.display = "none";
   };
};
  
  </script>
```

Comment: Wow, it was that simple! I really appreciate your help. We have found a really high client request volume for light boxes on their website, so this is going to be incredibly helpful. Thank's again!

Comment: No problem! Remember to upvote / mark as the accepted answer, to assist people with similar problems going forward. Glad to help!

Comment: Done! Thanks again